# Reading a 16-bit word via SPI from a current sensor [STM32 & CubeMx]

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm having problems to read my current sensor, which is located at the emitter leg of a power IGBT.

This is my sensor datasheet [TLI4970](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLI4970-D050T4-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625607bd1301562c43e04f38ad)

This is my routine every 10ms:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Bring slave select low
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&SPIRx, 2, 10); //Receive data
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //Bring slave select high
```

However, I get random values even when the current is zero. I'm getting values like:

```
0x8800

0x8803

0x8801

0xA7FF

0x87FC

0x97FE

0xA802

0xA801

0x97FD

0x87FD

0xA800

0xA7FE
```

According to the datasheet, these are sensor status messages, but none of them are Sensor Current Messages. The hardware seems okay. This sensor is not so common I think. I haven't found much help. What do you think the problem is? I can upload the whole code generated by CubeMx if needed.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? I find at times like these that actually probing to see what the bus is doing can be invaluable.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope by now. I'll see how I get one. In the meantime I've captured a new pattern of received data and all of them start at either 8 or A in the MSB position. I don't expect to receive "1" in the MSB bit after the first message which is the status. It's like noise, because if I ignore the 3 top bits, the measurement makes sense.

Comment: SPI has 4 modes with different clock polarity and edge, look if you selected correct mode.

Answer (score 1):

Those values are quite consistent. Remember than the higher bits contain the parity and your result is about 0x800 which is IMO correct. Remember that the current can flow in the both directions. So the zero will be minus max current, the middle value ( this is your case) represents zero and the max value represents the maximum current.